# Cognos: How to show shorten dates in a cross tab in report studio?

Tags: report, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have this report where in cross tabs the column header shows month and year in the format of "September 2014". I want it to show "Sept 2014" instead. Can someone help me with this?

The format is actually coming from the database table so me trying to change the data format property from the properties tab hasn't done anything.

I would appreciate any help and ideas on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
substring([Month/Year],1,4) || ' ' || substring([Month/Year],position(' ',[Month/Year]) + 1)
```

This will shorten the first word to 4 characters and retain the entire second word (the year in this case).

Comment: Thanks a lot Johnsonium!!